# Converting the shared last level cache to multiple private ones

Tags: caching, operating-system, cpu

Is there any way to convert a multicore CPU (particularly a CORE iX) with a shared last level cache to a CPU with multiple private caches each for one core? Any flag settable by OS or something like that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This will serve no purpose. I think you can do it on (older) AMD machines because I have read about it before. Not sure though. However, I don't think Intel allows access to its L3 cache in the manner you want. Furthermore, I see no benefit of doing this. Dedicating cache would mean you severely hamper computation time on multithreaded processes. Dedicating cache on single threaded applications is no different from keeping it as it was. Single threaded software would use up as much cache as it can anyways. What you could do is force that process to use only one core.